# add custom attribute to primary button of fluent ui

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, custom-attribute

I need a unique custom attribute on the clickable part of fluent ui primary button.
when I put on it custom attribute that starts with data-
for example

```
    <PrimaryButton data-testid="clickButton" 
    text={props.btnText} href={props.link} target="_blank"  />
```

it does work but if the custom attribute doesn't start with the word data- like in my case it just ignores it for example:

```
     <PrimaryButton digitaldata-collections="Export" 
     text={props.btnText} href={props.link} target="_blank"  />
```

it there another way to add it?